# How to use sed for replacing #x001c with blank?

Tags: linux, xml, sed

I am getting the below error while working on XML:-
XML Production Error: Character '#x001c' does not fulfill production 'CharData'.

I used sed command as below to remove the above character from the source XML file-

```
sed -i -E "s/#x001c//g" $src_file
```

Am I using the correct syntax for replacing the character '#x001c' with blank? Please confirm.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are using it correct except you do not need the `-E` flag as you are not using **extended regular expressions** in this case.  See `man sed` for explanations on the flags

So this will work (tested)

```
sed -i 's/#x001c//g' file.txt
```